# Does modifying a ASA tunnel create a downtime?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn

I inherited a cisco ASA, I never really had to manage one before. But, I need to modify an existing tunnel to add IP addresses to both the local and remote traffic selector, specifically there are already object groups for local ip addresses in the tunnel and remote ip addresses in the tunnel and I will be adding IPs to both those groups so they can communicate over the tunnel.

There are some sensitive applications communicating over this tunnel, will modifying the tunnel cause an interruption in traffic over the tunnel or should I be able to add things to this tunnel without interruption?

Comment: How are you planning to do it? Adding rules to the acl shouldn't break anything, but changing the acl or any other part of the tunnel configuration will cause it to drop. (each ACL is it's own SA, so adding ACLs shouldn't drop existing SAs. But this should be tested offline first -- it may reset to communicate the new ACL)

Comment: The ACL for the VPN has two object groups, and I'll be adding IPs to the object groups. So I wont be modifying the ACL directly, but I will be modifying the object groups referenced by the ACL